# Connection problem

Tags: wireless, ssh, https

I have some problems with the Wifi connection in my office with Ubuntu:

- Can not access facebook.
- Can't access my server via ssh.
- Can't access some websites using https protocol.

Note: this problem is not faced in Windows so it's not related to the access point, and this problem is faced in my case only with my office's access point.

I really appreciate your help !

Comment: can you please open "Additional drivers" and tell if there are any wifi driver name

Comment: No there is no additional drivers it's all about Maximum Transmission Unit.

Answer (score 2):

After some googling my problem is solved and here is the solution:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2110129&p=12480983#post1248098

Comment: use this link:http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2110129&p=12480983#post12480983

Comment: the above link is directly to the answer instead of question